# SDL.framework and Xcode are not playing nice

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks, sdl

I'm building a game on Mac OS X that uses SDL. However, SDL.framework is exhibiting peculiar behavior.

If SDL.framework exists in /Library/Frameworks as well as the application bundle, GDB spits up the following:

> objc[40787]: Class SDLTranslatorResponder is implemented in both /Users/Hinchy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Here_Comes_Launchman-abjymmujvjzdemcsrkkcmonahuva/Build/Products/Debug/Here Comes Launchman.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   objc[40787]: Class SDL_QuartzWindow is implemented in both /Users/Hinchy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Here_Comes_Launchman-abjymmujvjzdemcsrkkcmonahuva/Build/Products/Debug/Here Comes Launchman.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   objc[40787]: Class SDL_QuartzWindowDelegate is implemented in both /Users/Hinchy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Here_Comes_Launchman-abjymmujvjzdemcsrkkcmonahuva/Build/Products/Debug/Here Comes Launchman.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   objc[40787]: Class SDL_QuartzView is implemented in both /Users/Hinchy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Here_Comes_Launchman-abjymmujvjzdemcsrkkcmonahuva/Build/Products/Debug/Here Comes Launchman.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL and /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/A/SDL. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

The game then proceeds to crash with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS symbol at the first SDL_PollEvent.

If SDL.framework exists only in the application bundle (or does not exist at all), the game refuses to start at all.

If SDL.framework exists only in /Library/Frameworks, the game runs with no issues.

This *only* holds true for SDL.framework and not the other SDL derivatives (SDL_image, SDL_mixer, etc) I'm using in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:
[Embedding frameworks in a Mac App Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499232/embedding-frameworks-in-a-mac-app-bundle?rq=1)

Changing the

> Runpath Search Paths" build setting to "@loader_path/../Frameworks"

as was suggested erased that message from my output, and also allowed it to run without the SDL.framework in my /Library/Frameworks folder.